netCDF file without crs/Clipping to the shape file with projected shape file
Issues Encountered:
The NetCDF file has rotated grid coordinates (rlon, rlat), which adds complexity to aligning it with the shapefile.
When I try to clip the NetCDF data with the shapefile, I receive errors. I suspect this is related to handling the rotated grid coordinates or the CRS mismatch.
Question:
How can I correctly handle the rotated grid coordinates in the NetCDF file and align it with a shapefile that has EPSG:3003? What steps should I take to ensure that the CRS is properly assigned and that clipping operations work without errors?
Another problem issues is the attributes of the nc file, i have tried some codes to re-rotate back to normal lat ad lot but did not work at all.
Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated!
I've uploaded the NetCDF and shapefile that I'm working with. You can download them from the following link:
Download nc file, Here
Any help on how to correctly handle the CRS and clipping would be greatly appreciated!
import xarray
import xarray as xr
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import CRS

# Load shapefile and NetCDF dataset
gdf = gpd.read_file('path/to/your/shapefile.shp')
ds = xr.open_dataset('path/to/your/data.nc')

# Check CRS of shapefile and NetCDF
shapefile_crs = gdf.crs
netcdf_crs = CRS.from_user_input(ds.rio.crs) if ds.rio.crs else 
None

print("Shapefile CRS:", shapefile_crs)
print("NetCDF CRS:", netcdf_crs)

# Assign CRS if missing
if not shapefile_crs:
gdf = gdf.set_crs(netcdf_crs)
elif not netcdf_crs:
ds = ds.rio.write_crs(shapefile_crs, inplace=True)

# Attempt to clip NetCDF with shapefile
clipped_ds = ds.rio.clip(gdf.geometry, from_disk=True)


Welcome to SO. The question really needs more detail. If you can, read the guidance on "Ask Question" and modify the question. We do not have access to your shapefile or netCDF data, so it's impossible for anyone to able to provide a working solution. At a minimum, provide this data as part of the question

Apologies for the lack of detail—this is my first time using the platform. I'll provide the shapefile and NetCDF file shortly. Thank you for the guidance!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Sorry for not be able to upload the necessary files earlier, but now that i have uploaded , looking forward for some help, thank you all

Insofar as I am aware, you can only process data sets with variables in a rotated lat-long grid using the cf-python package. That package was developed by some of the people active on the CF Metadata Conventions, to which your data set obviously adheres, and it is labeled as the reference implementation of CF in Python.
On the CRS, this is very often not included in a netCDF file, especially not if it adheres to CF because there the default is longitude-latitude on an undefined sphere (typically one may assume WGS-84). In your case it is actually included but it describes the rotated grid (thus making it mandatory) so that's not much use. As per the CF recommendation, there are auxiliary coordinate variables "lon" and "lat" that give the longitude and latitude for each pixel in the data variable, "TOT_PREC" in this case. Although I have not used it myself, I am pretty sure that cf-python can deal with it.
In addition to that, there are errors in your netCDF file (which may be related to the error you asked about here). There are 24 time steps in your "time" dimension and they are all 3600 seconds apart. In the associated "time_bounds" bounds variable those bounds are specified in hours 0-24, but they should be in seconds (the unit of the "time" dimension) and envelop the "time" values (i.e. the first bound is time[0] - 1800, time[0] + 1800, etc).

Given that I am not an expert on this matter, I do Appreciate the answers, is there any way in which I just change this rotated coordinate to the normal ones, and get the data to represent naturally where it is located, instead of this all-complex level computation?       right after I have downloaded and load the NC file in QGIS, the location of the data is far from where it supposed to be. because of this rotation, my goal is to clip this NC file to the small shapefile in that area, now i cannot do that as the shape file and the netCDF file are absolutely not representing the same area

I'm afraid there is no easy solution. If you look at the CORDEX EURO domain (https://cordex.org/domains/cordex-region-euro-cordex/), as an example of a data holding with rotated grid over Europe, you'll find that the rotated grids use longitude and latitudes in the range of (roughly) [(-28...18), (-23...22)] (so that's around a fictitious [0, 0]) while the ground lon-lat are about [(-45...65), (22...72)]. An option would be to reproject the data using the Oblique projection but not many software tools support that.

Ok thank you for your kind suggestions
